# Finding the determinant of a $4\times4$ matrix using row reduction.

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

> Finding the determinant of a $4\times4$ matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

I did row transformations and finally got upper triangular matrix
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 & 0 \end{vmatrix}_{R_3+R_1->R_3\mbox{ and } R_4-3R_1->R_4}$$
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\ 0 & -5 & -1 & 0 \end{vmatrix}_{3R_3-2R_2\mbox{ and }3R_4+5R_2->R_4}$$
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 10 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 5 \end{vmatrix}_{5r_4-R_3->R_4}$$
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 10 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 \end{vmatrix}$$
To find the determinant I need to multiply the diagonal elements of the matrix. So, $1\times3\times10\times24=720$. But, however the answer is $16$. I cannot understand where I did a mistake.

Comment: It's impossible to know what you did wrong without seeing the intermediate steps.  I would guess you multiplied a row by a number somewhere along the line.  It's okay to add a multiple of one row to another, but if you just plain multiply a row by a constant, you multiply the determinant by the same constant.

Comment: @saulspatz I added my steps now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you can add a multiple of one row to another without changing the determinant, so $R_1+R_3\to R_3$ is fine.  However, when you do $3R_4+5R_2\to R_4,$ you have really done two operations:
$$\begin{align}
3R_4&\to R_4\\
R_4+5R_2&\to R_4
\end{align}$$
The first of these multiplies the determinant by $3$.

Comment: Can you explain where I was wrong in the calculation.

Comment: I think I just did.  When you performed the operation $3R_4+5R_2\to R_4,$ you unintentionally multiplied the determinant by $3.$  What is unclear?

Comment: I multiplied the determinant by $3$ so that I could get $0$ in the last row second column

Comment: It's fine to multiply the row by $3$, but you have to realize that you've also multiplied the determinant by $3$.  The matrix you have has three times the determinant you're trying to compute, so when you compute its determinant, you have to divide by $3$ to get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out.  I was afraid you hadn't, and was trying to figure out how else to explain it, when the check mark came up!

Answer (score 3):

Let me tell you, that your triangular matrix is wrong.
It would have been possible for us to spot out the mistake, if you had given more steps.

Look at the Image below, Thats your triangular matrix(Using [Matrix Calculator](https://matrixcalc.org/en/#Gaussian-elimination%28%7B%7B1,2,1,0%7D,%7B0,3,1,1%7D,%7B-1,0,3,1%7D,%7B3,1,2,0%7D%7D%29))

[image]

The determinant of the matrix is 16.
The Triangular Matrix is

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  2 &1 &0 \\  0 &  3 &1 &1 \\ 0 &  0  &\frac{10}{3} &\frac{1}{3} \\0 &  0 &0 &\frac{8}{5} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I added my steps. Can you now tell where I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

We need also to take into account the coefficients we have used to combine the rows indeed multiplying a row by $k$ of $A$ to obtain $A’$, we have $$\det(A’)=k\cdot \det(A)$$